# react navigation type for typescript in component screen props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a warning or error for `navigation` props in component screen

```
export default function FoodMenuList({ navigation }) {}
```

because I dont assign type for `navigation`

`Binding element 'navigation' implicitly has an 'any'`

I tried to search navigation props type for react navigation, but I dont find

what is react-navigation navigation props type?

or may be?

```
export default function FoodMenuList({ navigation }: {navigation: {navigate:Function}}) {}
```

or may be there is better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation provided by react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-screens

> To type check our screens, we need to annotate the navigation prop and the route prop received by a screen. The navigator packages in React Navigation export a generic types to define types for both the navigation and route props from the corresponding navigator.

For example, you can use NativeStackScreenProps for the Native Stack Navigator.

```
import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
};

type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;
```

> This allows us to type check route names and params which you're navigating using navigate, push etc. The name of the current route is necessary to type check the params in route.params and when you call setParams.

Then you can use the Props type you defined above to annotate your component.

For function components:

```
function ProfileScreen({ route, navigation }: Props) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the `useNavigation` hook from `@react-navigation/native`, check the docs [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/)

> useNavigation is a hook which gives access to navigation object. It's useful when you cannot pass the navigation prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.

you can also write

```
interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationType;
}

FoodMenuList({ navigation }: Props)
```

if you're using class component or you don't wont to use `useNavigation`